# Is it possible to do tail-recursion on a method which returns ZIO?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, zio

For example:

```
def foo(bar: String): UIO[String] = {
    for {
      f <- UIO("baz")
      res <- foo(f)
    } yield res
  }
```

seems like that it's impossible because the last line is a mapping function

Comment: you never use `bar`, is that right?

Comment: in fact, if you never use `bar`, it will recurse forever

Comment: @joelb Actually it will not recurse forever https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rbtOMPlHRzaGCJ3zC16s6Q

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your function

```
def foo(bar: String): UIO[String] = {
  for {
    f <- UIO[String]("baz")
    res <- foo(f)
  } yield res
}
```

as

```
def foo(bar: String): UIO[String] = {
  UIO[String]("baz").flatMap(f =>
    foo(f)
  )
}
```

without extra `.map`.

It's clear that your function is not tail-recursive.

If you're interested in stack safety you can use `scala.util.control.TailCalls`, [`cats.free.Trampoline`](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/stackless-scala-with-free-monads.html) or [`cats.Monad#tailRecM`](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/tail-recursive-monads.html)

```
import cats.Monad
import zio.UIO
import zio.interop.catz.core._

Monad[UIO].tailRecM(??? /* starting value */)(a => ??? /* effectful calculation to be repeated until it returns Right */)
```

There were [troubles](https://github.com/zio/zio/issues/779) with implementation of `tailRecM` for `ZIO` but currently the issue is closed.

Comment: I was shown that using https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for can make you keep the for comprehension and still have heap saftey.